# Did Allah prescribe the Hadiths?

Tags: hadith

Does the Qur'an state that the traditions of Muhammad should be written down and followed?

Comment: No, There is no verse that states that... It is up to the hadith or companions to decide if it should be written or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the Quran doesn't specify everything, for example it does say that you should pray but it doesn't give a detailed explanation of how you should pray.

Similarly the quran says that we should follow the the prophet(PBUH):

> O you who have believed, **obey Allah and obey the Messenger** and those in authority among you. And if you disagree over anything, **refer it to Allah and the Messenger**, if you should believe in Allah and the Last Day. That is the best [way] and best in result.[4:59](http://tanzil.net/#4:59)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I do have a follow-up question. 4:59 says "... and those in authority among you ...". I was under the impression that there was no 'authority' in Islam (unlike, say, Catholicism). Am I missing something? (If this is too big a question then let me know and I'll post a new thread.)

Comment: @user there are different interpretations of what "authority" means... The most dominating opinion is that they are the ulema because of their great knowledge about islam.

Answer (score 1):

What are the traditions that Muhammad PB-UH have ? Muhammad had never came up with traditions but he came with values, whats a tradition ? a tradition is an attitude that one person or a group of people had developed by time regardless if it is right or wrong and their offspring had followed it without any conscious contribution, does the prophet do so ? Allah says in the Quran :

> " وَنَزَّلْنَا عَلَيْكَ الْكِتَابَ تِبْيَاناً لِكُلِّ شَيْءٍ وَهُدىً وَرَحْمَةً وَبُشْرَى لِلْمُسْلِمِينَ " النحل:الآية89

this is the difference between a value and a tradition, a value is the assumption of an ethical action with regard and worth, it means after a deep conscious cooking of the idea you search just for the ethical in it and you give just the good in it, that's values as the prophet PB-UH came up with, if you search in all the Sunnah books from cover to cover you are going to find only value but never traditions.

To respond directly to your question, the Qur'an state that the values that Muhammad came up with should be written down and followed, so Allah mandated Muslims to emulate the practices of Muhammad as he practiced them. as Allah says :

> قل إن كنتم تحبون الله فاتبعوني يحببكم الله ويغفر لكم ذنوبكم والله غفور رحيم (آل عمران:31)

Also to remove any other doubts about this subject we must say that any thing that Muhammad says by his tongue is a revelation, as allah says in the Quran :

> وَمَا يَنطِقُ عَنِ الْهَوَى* إِنْ هُوَ إِلَّا وَحْيٌ يُوحَى" النجم : 3-4

He also says :

> هُوَ الَّذِي بَعَثَ فِي الْأُمِّيِّينَ رَسُولًا مِّنْهُمْ يَتْلُو عَلَيْهِمْ آيَاتِهِ وَيُزَكِّيهِمْ وَيُعَلِّمُهُمُ الْكِتَابَ وَالْحِكْمَةَ وَإِن كَانُوا مِن قَبْلُ لَفِي ضَلَالٍ مُّبِينٍ" الجمعة : 2

Comment: In the context of Islamic theology the word 'tradition' means 'a saying or act ascribed to the Prophet but not recorded in the Qur'an'. So I don't feel that you've addressed the question: where is the mandate for the Sunnah?

Comment: @user2584283 you say : "In the context of Islamic theology the word 'tradition' means 'a saying or act ascribed to the Prophet but not recorded in the Qur'an" ! a "saying or act ascribed to the Prophet but not recorded in the Qur'an" it is called sunnah and it is far away from being a tradition, a sunnah is a set of values not traditions because valueus are clear in the context and ethical but a tradition it could be fuzzy and unethical, this is how i understand your question if you see that i haven't respond, please feel free to clarify your question, thank you ...

Comment: Replace 'tradition' with whatever word you feel comfortable with. The question is whether Allah mandated Muslims to emulate the practices of Muhammad.

Comment: @user2584283 i have developed my response to respond directly to your question, thank you ...

Comment: "To respond directly to your question, the Qur'an state that the values that Muhammad came up with should be written down and followed." Great, could you specify the verses please?

Comment: @user2584283 response edited to match your need, thank you ....

Comment: Are there any other verses? I can't read Arabic but the English translation of 3:31 says 'Say, [O Muhammad], "If you should love Allah, then follow me, [so] Allah will love you and forgive you your sins. And Allah is Forgiving and Merciful."' I would interpret that to mean you should follow the teachings of Allah as mediated by Muhammad - not follow the teachings of Muhammad himself...

Comment: i see that you don't know arabic well brother ? anyway that's not a problem, no the translation is wrong, allah in this verse is talking in the tongue of Muhammad (in the place of Muhammad) PBUH as you can notice in the begining of this Ayya when Allah says : " O muhammas say" what he should say ? then Allah completed the Ayya : "If you were loving Allah, then follow me, Allah will love you and he will forgive you your sins. And Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.  ", i will enforce the response by another Ayya when allah declares that any thing that Muhammad says by his tongue is a revelation.

Comment: Why not citing this verse that has an obvious implication as to the necessity of learning about Prophet's Sunnah: " You have an excellent example in the Messenger of God; for anyone who seeks God and the Last Day, and remembers God frequently. [(33:21)](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.itani/33:21)

Comment: @infatuated yes good, there's a lot of Ayyas but this is what i remember now, thanks for for the good add ....

Comment: "To respond directly to your question, the Qur'an state that the values that Muhammad came up with should be written down and followed" 
how do you come up with this conclusion? and please write a translation of ayaat or explain what they are saying in English. this community use English as primary language and when somebody try to find an answer to their question, they may not know Arabic.